# Cocoapod spec with separate frameworks per sub spec

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm struggling with creating a cocoapod spec including multiple sub specs where each sub spec should be its own framework.
Basically I have the following spec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name     = 'BMCommons'
  ...
  s.default_subspec = 'BMCore'

  s.subspec 'BMCore' do |s_core|
    s_core.header_dir = 'BMCore'
    ...
  end

  s.subspec 'BMUICore' do |s_uicore|
    s_uicore.header_dir = 'BMUICore'
    ...
  end
end
```

Now I would like this to result in a BMCore.framework and BMUICore.framework instead of one BMCommons.framework. Is this possible or do I need to create multiple specs to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

In short: no, you can't have subspecs that result in different frameworks, because - as the name implies - it's a **sub**spec, that is part of something. From the cocoapod [docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec):

> **subspec**
>
> Represents specification for a module of the library.

But it will result in separate frameworks internally when you use it in a project, their filenames being **BMCommons-BMCore** and **BMCommons-BMUICore**. Their actual framework name you import will remain **BMCommons**.

You can try this out by creating a project with 2 targets, and in the Podfile for one target you add the first subspec, and for the other the second one. After a *pod install* you should look the targets in the **Pods** project, there are the generated frameworks by cocoapod.